# How to decide if a user's anonymous operator is linear

Tags: matlab, user-defined-functions

If I'm getting a anonymous operator from a user I would like to test (extremely quickly) if the operator is linear. Is there a standard way to do this? I have no way of doing symbolic operators, or parsing the function.  Is the only way trying some random functions (what random functions do I choose) and seeing if they satisfy linearity??

Thanks in advance.

Context:

User supplies a black box operator, that is a function which takes functions to functions.

I can give the operator a function and I get a function back. I want to determine if the operator is linear?  Is there a standard fast method which gives me high confidence?

Comment: I meant, what environment are you talking about?

Comment: Matlab but the user can potentially supply the operator in any compatible code... but if it makes it easier assume the operator function is in Matlab as well...

Answer (score 3):

No, not without sweeping the entire parameter space.  Imagine the following:

```
@(f) @(x) f(x) + (x == 1e6)
```

This operator is non-linear, but there's no way of knowing that unless you happen to test at `x == 1e6`.

**UPDATE**

As others have suggested, it may be "good enough" to determine a domain of interest, and check for linearity at periodic intervals across the domain.  This may give you false positives (i.e. suggest an operator is linear when in fact it's non-linear), but never false negatives.

Comment: If you were given the function how would you tell from parsing the string... it that an option?

Comment: @alext87: I imagine the classification problem would become very difficult, very quickly.  Imagine `@(f) @(x) f(x) + (x == 1e6) + (x ~= 1e6) - 1`; this is linear, but it's not obvious what the rule would be to classify it as such.

Comment: So no-one has had this problem before. Linear and non-linear cases need to be treated differently in so many areas...

Comment: @alext87: So what is the overall problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @alext87: Many have had this problem before. However, since there is no easy solution for the general case, they either specify in the documentation that a function only accepts either linear or non-linear cases, or they ask the user to specify whether it's linear or non-linear, or they limit the operators to a small set which can then be parsed and tested, or they try running as linear first and switch to non-linear if the program fails.

Comment: Additionally, in areas such as engineering, assumptions will be made that if a function is approximately linear in the range of interest then it can be treated as such. A simple 'sampling' test could therefore be used, with sensible choices made about the range to sample over.

Answer (score 0):

This is information the user should supply. Add a parameter `linear` true/false, default to false (I'm assuming that the code for non-linear will work for linear too, just taking more time).

The problem with random testing is that you will classify a non-linear function as linear sooner or later, and then the user has a problem, because your function *unpredictably* produces **wrong results** (depending on which points you pick randomly), that may be reasonably close to the correct results, ie people may not notice for a *loooong* time --> this is a recipe for disaster.

Really, the user should know this in the first place, its *very* important to avoid false positives and as said before there is no completely reliable way to test this. Save yourself the trouble and add an additional parameter.